# Start showing the column of code on right in WebStorm

Tags: ide, settings, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I start showing the column of code on right in WebStorm and basically in any JetBrains product?

So that it was easier for you to get what I asking I will show you an example:

[image]

Here we can see a column of code on right in Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you please clarify for me (since I'm not familiar with modern Visual Studio) what that "column of code" shows? So far my guess is that you need **CodeGlance plugin** (will show a code minimap similar to what Sublime has).

Comment: @LazyOne, yep. Your guess is right.